# Transaction verified but didn't arrive at destination wallet?

Tags: transactions, wallet

First time using bitcoin so after a lengthy verification process I got transaction confirmed via moonpay.

But it hasn't seemed to have arrived at the destination wallet.

So either it did arrive or didn't, but from what I read up and checked it looks like it did just wondering if any way to know for sure? and can learn for next time.

Transaction ID: *5782f49e-c87e-407c-82cb-a1856e8fe96c*

Destination wallet address: *1HETiEbuV2q4mPrJmtLLZgzWBZAGLLqJiN*

Transaction hash:   *2213b1a0d552bd7c73b2597ef0b0df2d18a8984be6a876417cb049ff666b1d39*

Comment: It did arrive, is that your wallet or someone else's? If it's yours, if you could add the name of the wallet software you are using, we can find why you didn't receive.

Comment: No, it was sent to someone else's, but since then I've added my own wallet via Atomic Wallet App.

Comment: On any block explorer the transaction is shown as confirmed, there is no mistake or problem on your part. If they aren't your acquaintance, they might be trying to scam you so that you send to them again, but if you trust them it's very likely that there is something they need to fix with their wallet. In the end they should be able to access those coins.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time, would you have suggestion for best wallet software to use? at any use/feedback on Atomic Wallet? thanks again

Comment: I've heard about that wallet for the first time. It's not open source so no one can review their code. I'd suggest using a known and preferably open-source wallet, such as BRD, blockchain wallet, or any wallet that has lots of downloads and online reviews. I also suggest [bitcoin.org choose your wallet page](https://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet)